# Trying to call method on dict, getting AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'update' is read-only

Tags: python, dictionary, attributeerror

I have no idea what is wrong or what causes the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'update' is read-only
```

on the following code:

```
map = []
point1back = {}
point1fwd = {}
point1back.update = {'nextHop':point1Fwd, 'direction':1, 'distance':0}
point1fwd.update = {'nextHop':point1Fwd, 'direction':3, 'distance':160}
map.append(point1back)
map.append(point1fwd)
```

Comment: `p.update = args` is not how you call an object's method, you want `p.update(args)`. That code tries to reassign/override the dict's builtin `update()` method, which is definitely not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dict.update` is a method, not a variable you can assign a value to. Try this instead:

```
point1back.update({'nextHop':point1Fwd, 'direction':1, 'distance':0})
```